# asp.net vb web application printing data to a sticky label machine from web server

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a website where i'm pulling some data from a query and then needing to print this data to a brady pr300 plus label printer. I would like for the printing to happen automatically from the web server to the printer without having the print dialog box pop up on the client computer.

What is the best way to go about this? javascript, vb behind code?

I've been playing around with this without much luck. I created a printingclass with onbeginprint method and onprintpage method. When i call the print, it goes to the onbeginprint method, but for some reason it doesnt go to onprintpagemethod when i step through the code. The error i get is System.Drwaing.Printing.invalidprinterexception: no printers are installed.

I'm kind of stuck at the moment.

```
Public Sub PrintDocument()
    Dim tprinter As New PCPrint
    tprinter.PrinterFont = New Font("Verdana", 10)
    tprinter.TextToPrint = "HELLO WORLD"
    tprinter.PrintName = "testbrady"
    tprinter.Print()
End Sub
```

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnBeginPrint(ByVal e As Printing.PrintEventArgs)
    ' Run base code
    MyBase.OnBeginPrint(e)

    'Check to see if the user provided a font
    'if they didnt then we default to Times New Roman
    If _font Is Nothing Then
        'Create the font we need
        _font = New Font("Times New Roman", 10)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPrintPage(ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    ' Run base code
    MyBase.OnPrintPage(e)

    'Declare local variables needed
    Static curChar As Integer
    Dim printHeight As Integer
    Dim printWidth As Integer
    Dim leftMargin As Integer
    Dim rightMargin As Integer
    Dim lines As Int32
    Dim chars As Int32

    'Set print area size and margins
    With MyBase.DefaultPageSettings
        printHeight = .PaperSize.Height - .Margins.Top - .Margins.Bottom
        printWidth = .PaperSize.Width - .Margins.Left - .Margins.Right
        leftMargin = .Margins.Left 'X
        rightMargin = .Margins.Top   'Y
    End With

    MyBase.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrintName

    'Check if the user selected to print in Landscape mode
    'if they did then we need to swap height/width parameters
    If MyBase.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape Then
        Dim tmp As Integer
        tmp = printHeight
        printHeight = printWidth
        printWidth = tmp
    End If

    'Now we need to determine the total number of lines
    'we're going to be printing
    Dim numLines As Int32 = CInt(printHeight / PrinterFont.Height)

    'Create a rectangle printing are for our document
    Dim printArea As New RectangleF(leftMargin, rightMargin, printWidth, printHeight)

    'Use the StringFormat class for the text layout of our document
    Dim format As New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)

    'Fit as many characters as we can into the print area      

    e.Graphics.MeasureString(_text.Substring(RemoveZeros(curChar)), PrinterFont, New SizeF(printWidth, printHeight), format, chars, lines)

    'Print the page
    e.Graphics.DrawString(_text.Substring(RemoveZeros(curChar)), PrinterFont, Brushes.Black, printArea, format)

    'Increase current char count
    curChar += chars

    'Detemine if there is more text to print, if
    'there is the tell the printer there is more coming
    If curChar < _text.Length Then
        e.HasMorePages = True
    Else
        e.HasMorePages = False
        curChar = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello StackOverflow Members,

This is what i ended up doing to get the label printer to work.

```
 Imports System.Drawing
 Imports System.Drawing.Printing


    Public Sub prt(variables)
       Dim prn As New Printing.PrintDocument
       Dim psz As New Printing.PaperSize With {
            .RawKind = Printing.PaperKind.Custom,
            .Width = 400,
            .Height = 150
        }

    Using (prn)
        prn.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer
        prn.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psz
        prn.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 5
        prn.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 5
        prn.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 5
        prn.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 5
        AddHandler prn.PrintPage,
           AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
        prn.Print()
        RemoveHandler prn.PrintPage,
           AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
    End Using

    End Sub

 Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
       ByVal args As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

        Dim shopnameX As Integer = 10, shopnameY As Integer = 10
        Dim sfont As New Font("Arial Black", 14)
        Dim strfomart As New StringFormat()
        Dim StrRight As New StringFormat()
        Dim StrLeft As New StringFormat()
        strfomart.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        StrRight.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
        StrLeft.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near

       Dim dashValues As Single() = {5, 2, 5, 2}
        Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
        ' blackPen.DashPattern = dashValues
        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
        args.Graphics.DrawString(part.ToString, sfont, Brushes.Black, New 
            PointF(shopnameX, shopnameY))
 End Sub
```